# Why Refresh [f5] is different then Enter from the address bar and press Enter key?

Tags: performance, firefox, caching

I have making benchmarking on the application I have I found a thing who amazed me and I want to clear the things that why both are different.

pressing in Address bar and press enter open my page in 1.5 to 3 seconds)

if I press Refresh button in Firefox it's take long time then press enter (3 to 6 second)

I really not know what thing's matter here. are refresh button not take image , css or js from cache.

Are anyone specify me what things matter here.

Comment: It seems to me that the main issue is that your page takes 3 to 6 seconds to load.

Comment: I don't know what actually happens, but if you refresh on a long page, most browsers remember how far you were scrolled down and place you there when the page is done loading.  I'm pretty sure it saves and restores any form (including hidden) input values.  The extra stuff it keeps track of might slow it down.

Comment: I have something better than just the speed difference! I found a problem on a certain website. I had a link that redirected me to another website but I got 403 error. Refreshing did nothing, still 403, but when I pressed ENTER, I got access to the resource! I still have no idea why that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP requests sent differ. By pressing enter, you tell the browser to navigate to some page and apply normal resource caching behavior (just like clicking a link). This means that the linked CSS file which takes 2 seconds to generate on the server and was sent with: "Max-Age: 1 year" header, will not be fetched again if it is available in local cache.

With F5, you explicitly tell the browser to refresh the resources used on the page. Typically image/css/js files are requested again, and resources are not fetched with "If-Modified-Since" or "If-None-Match" headers.

I don't think this is part of any specification, but it makes sense to web developers if they see server resource changes reflected regardless of caching rules.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you have hidden form data somewhere. If you hit f5, Firefox will resend that data (sometimes accompanied by a warning message to that effect). If you just hit Enter, it's a new, 'clean' request for the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

It probably redraws the page contents from the memory. Pressing F5 will definitely make the browser to make HEAD http requests for all files used in the page. Subsequently, the browser will make GET requests for newer files. This would explain the delay.